# Permissões de pasta wordpress - 500 Internal Server

Tags: wordpress

Meu Wordpress estava funcionando normalmente, fui editar as permissões por questão de segurança.

Atribuí a todas as pastas dentro do meu `public_html` para 755 e atribui para todos os meus arquivos para 644

Pois bem, agora só da `500 Internal Server ao acessar`

Também pensei que fosse meu `htaccess`

Hoje ele está assim:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://MEULINK.com/.*$      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://MEULINK.com$      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://MEULINK.com/.*$      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://MEULINK.com$      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://MEUIP/.*$      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://MEUIP$      [NC]
RewriteRule .*\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|bmp)$ - [F,NC]

#security

<FilesMatch ^wp-config.php$>
Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

Options All –Indexes
```

Pode ser alguma atribuição errada? Ou problema no meu host?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seguindo as regras do Wordpress, todo diretório deve ter: **chmod 755 ou 750**.
Todos os arquivos devem ter: **chmod 644 ou 640**(Exceto o arquivo wp-config.php, este arquivo deverá ter chmod 600 para evitar leituras).
Atenção: Nenhum diretório deverá ter chmod 777 (nem mesmo o uploads), o PHP trabalha com permissões proprietáriass e pode escrever até mesmo em um diretório 755.

Essas são as regras do Wordpress para File Permissions, caso ajude estou enviando meu .htaccess padrão:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Não se esqueça que existem diferenças em usar o chmod xxx ou chmod -R xxx, entender essas diferenças irão te ajudar a resolver.

Enfim, postei um workaround e um certo conhecimento, espero que isso te ajude!

Answer (score 1):

Podem ser diversas coisas, mas segue uma lista do que você pode tentar.

- Instala uma outra instância de wordpress no teu host; Se funcionar, não é problema do teu host.
- Remove a opção de permalinks e deleta teu .htaccess e vê se funciona.
- Em último caso, transfere tua pasta de temas (e os caminhos do db) pra instância nova.